# VB.NET Load Async Dummy CrystalReport Function

Tags: vb.net, async-await, crystal-reports

I am trying to load dummy crystal report document on Form Load so that Crystal Report dll gets loaded in memory.

```
Private Sub Reports_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim swatch As New Stopwatch
    swatch.Start()
    Cryload()
    swatch.Stop()
    Label6.Text = swatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString
End Sub

Private Async Function Cryload() As Task
    Dim rpt As New ReportDocument
    Await Task.Run(Sub() rpt.Load("Reports\Dummy.rpt"))

End Function
```

If I run without Crystal Report Document Load the time to load Form is 22 milliseconds.
If I run Cryload() with out Async Load time is 23746 milliseconds.
If I run Cryload() with Async/Await Load time is 14020 milliseconds.

I am sure I am missing something, is there a way to reduce the Form Load time.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you Awaiting the load? You only need to start a task to load the DLL and continue. If you need to ensure that the load has completed then store the task in a form level variable and check that it has completed.

Comment: I would not require to know if the task has completed, but the task to load the dll takes 23.746 seconds and during that every thing freezes. I am looking at solution where I can run this task parallel to the UI i.e UI to be responsive as task does it job in background.

Comment: Looks like this is code is pretty fast in i5 system with just 141 milliseconds to load, I do coding on i3 6th system to see if its fast enough for my system then it will be fast in others too.  Until I find better code looks like this will work and hopefully others can use it too.

Comment: The point here is that Await will freeze the UI of a non Async event like Reports_Load. You simply need to start a task in Reports_Load and then ignore it. No awaiting etc.